# How to access a function in block class from phtml?

Tags: blocks

i have a class see

```
class Magestore_RewardPoints_Helper_Block_Spend extends Magestore_RewardPoints_Helper_Calculation_Abstract {

}
```

which with a function

getCheckboxRules() inside, i need to access this function in a 
app\design\frondend\default\mytheme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want get of function of helper class then we below

For,helper:

```
Mage::helper('modulename/rest_ofclass')->yourFunction();
```

That means

For You case:
`Mage::helper('modulename/rest_ofclass')->yourFunction()`;

modulename/rest_ofclass

1) `modulename` depends on helper class deceleration on  your config.xml.)

```
<helpers>
    <modulename>
        <class>Magestore_RewardPoints_Helper</class>
    </modulename>
</helper>
```

2) `rest_ofclass` (Magestore_RewardPoints_Helper)rest of class from `Block_Spend`

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure whether the class you mentioned above is a `Block` or `Helper`.

If it is Block, you can do:

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('class_name/remaining_class_name')->getCheckboxRules();
```

and if it is `Helper`:

```
Mage::Helper('class_name/remaining_class_name')->getCheckboxRules();
```

Where

- `class_name` is name of registered class name in `Block`/`Model`/`Helper` in your module. Check `config.xml` file of the module.

---

#### For Example:

If you want to use `Mage_Core_Block_Template_Facade` Block from `core/Mage` files. You can use:

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('core/template_facade');
```

Where

- `core` text in the above code can be found from `core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml`

  ```
  <blocks>  <!-- line#91 in Magento 1.8.0 -->
      <core>
          <class>Mage_Core_Block</class>
      </core>
  </blocks>
  ```
- From above, `Mage_Core_Block` can be converted to `core`

[image]